# Workflow question: How to fix missing com_messages text?

Tags: joomla-4.x, emails, administration

Whenever a user submits and article on one of my sites, the message that comes across has only COM_MESSAGES_NEW_MESSAGE as the subject and COM_MESSAGES_NEW_MESSAGE_BODY. I've tried several things, including updating the language overrides and modifying the email templates. Neither of those has worked, so I'm guessing there's an issue elsewhere else. I want certain users to be notified when a new article is published and saved as a draft, so they can review and publish. Is there a different way to accomplish this, or can the private message notification be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the very same problem. This currently, i.e. November 2022, is a bug in Joomla 4.

##### Update

There is a nicer workaround to the one I posted initially. Updating my answer to show both.

### Workaround 1

1. Login to the backdend, select *System* on the left, then *Mail Templates* under *Templates*
   [image: Go to Mail Templates Customization]
2. Locate the mail template which is being used to notify about new articles. The title may vary depending on the backend language in use, but the **ID** does not. Look for ID `com_messages.new_message`
   [image: Locate the com_messages.new_message template]
3. One after the other, click the little flag icons representing the installed languages. This will open the template in the editor
   [image: Mail template in the Editor]
   The language keys, e.g. `COM_MESSAGES_NEW_MESSAGE` are already translated to the correct language value before the template is shown (this is the backend, and localization does work here). All you need to do is to verify, then click on `SAVE`.
4. Optional, if curious: Have a look into the Joomla DB to see what this has done. I can't tell how you can look into the Joomla DB in your environment, but if often is the *phpAdmin* web interface.
   Locate table `<prefix>_mail_templates`, display its content and look for the entries with `template_id` equal to `com_messages.new_message`.
   [image]
   In my case, there are two languages installed: The standard `en-GB`, and my local `de-CH`, so there are now three templates, the default with no language set, and one for each language.

The notification about new articles being submitted from the frontend will now send a message in the language set for the *backend*.

### Workaround 2

As an alternative workaround, make sure you set the *default* language for the *Site*, as well as the *Administrator* to the same language.

1. Login to the backdend, select *System* on the left, then *Language* under *Manage*
   [image: Backend Select Language Settings]
   Note: This is how the backend looks like at Joomla 4.2.5 with English as *Administrator* language. It is the first entry labelled *Language*, not the second one labelled *Content Languages* which is to be selected.
2. Select *Administrator*, and *Site* one after the other in the top drop down, and set the *Detault* to the same language.
   [image: Backend Set Default Languages]

This is a bit awkward, since I personally like to have the backend in the Joomla standard language, English, because helpfull Internet content is mostly in refering to the English terms.

### Joomla Issue Tracker item

I have filed a Joomla Issue Tracker report, and hope the bug will be fixed eventually: [[#39228] - Mail notifying about new article is not properly built when site and backend languages are different](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/39228)

Comment: Thank you! I had English (UK) as the only language for both site & admin, but didn't have it selected as the admin default. After ensuring that it was starred as the default, the messages started working again.